# Minimize the sum of distances between a sample and two "centers"

Tags: statistics, regression, clustering

Suppose we have a set of readings $\{X_{i}\}$, each of which is a real number.

What I want is to find 2 numbers, $a$ and $b$, such that

minimize the sum of distances between each $X_{i}$ and whichever is closer to it

$$
\large i.e. \sum_{i}^{ } min(|X_{i}-a|,|X_{i}-b|)
$$

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: maybe you are looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering

Comment: @BGM Awesome! That is what I'm looking for, thank you!